# Help on line integral $\int\limits_\gamma \frac{1}{(z + 1)(z + 2) \cdot \ldots \cdot (z + r)} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, line-integrals, singularity

I need help on the following line integral:
$$\int\limits_\gamma f dz = \int\limits_\gamma \frac{1}{g} dz = \int\limits_\gamma \frac{1}{(z + 1)(z + 2) \cdot \ldots \cdot (z + r)} dz$$
For a fix $r \in \mathbb{N} : r \ge 1$ where $\gamma : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}, \gamma(t) = 2r \cdot e^{2\pi i t}$. So, the line is the border of a disk with radius $2r$, i.e. $\partial D_{2r}(0)$ if you are more familiar with this notation.

I am allowed to use the **full tool box** of the complex analysis for this exercise.

We directly see all `singularities` of the function: $-1, -2, \ldots , -r$.
Also they are `isolated`, and obviously all of them are `simple poles`. The `winding number` of all is $1$.

The integral is given by:
$$\int\limits_\gamma fdz = 2\pi i \cdot (\operatorname{res}_{-1} + \operatorname{res}_{-2} + \ldots + \operatorname{res}_{-r})$$

So far so good. Now I know some methods for computing `residue` of `simple poles`, for example:
$$\operatorname{res}_{-a} = (z + a) f(z)|_{z = -a} = \frac{1}{(1 - a)(2 - a) \cdot \ldots \cdot ((a - 1) - a) \cdot ((a + 1) - a) \cdot \ldots \cdot (r - a)}$$
Or this one:
$$\operatorname{res}_{-a} = \frac{1}{g'(-a)}$$
However, those approaches seem to be very complex as I do not see where some term simplifies. I assume something simplifies when everything is put together in $(\operatorname{res}_{-1} + \operatorname{res}_{-2} + \ldots + \operatorname{res}_{-r})$ but I can not see the **trick**.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try to explicitly calculate few residues eg at -1,... . Res -1 is related to a factorial.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $r\geq 2$ and we consider the integral over a large circle centered at the origin with radius $R$, such integral $\phantom{}^{(A)}$ is bounded by a quantity tends to zero as $R\to +\infty$, so the sum of the residues (at $z=-1,z=-2,\ldots,z=-r$) is zero, just like the integral over $|z|=2r$.  The case $r=1$ is trivial.

$(A)$: For instance, in the $r=3$ case:
$$ \left|\int_{|z|=R}\frac{dz}{(z+1)(z+2)(z+3)}\right|\leq \frac{2\pi R}{(R-3)^3}.$$

Comment: In the exercise the $r$ is fix, no limit. Is this then also the case? I mean, it maybe tends to $0$ for increasing $r$ but what is it for a given fix $r$?

Comment: @Zabuza: ask yourself what is the difference between the integral over $\gamma_R$ and $\gamma_{2r}$. I would say zero, since the integrand function is holomorphic over the annulus $2r\leq |z|\leq R$.